# Python: How to remove shortchuts in pdb

Tags: python, debugging, shortcut, pdb, spyder

Simple and maybe obvious but not for us yet:
Using **pdb** shortcuts becomes annoying when there are same name variables to the commands, therefore, **how to remove all key shortcuts in pdb?** We use `pdb` in `spyder`, BTW.

```
>>> p = 1
```

while trying to debug the above `p` appears as command (abr. for print) while we are interested in our variable! *Confusing!*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(*Spyder dev here*) According to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands) you need to prefix variable names with `!` if their names are the same that `pdb` commands. That's the easy way to solve your problem.

The hard way is to define your own `sitecustomize`, subclass `pdb.Pdb` and redefine it's `do_p`, `do_d`, `do_b` methods to print your variables. You can check out how we subclass `pdb.Pdb` for our own purposes [here](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/source/browse/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py#353), in case you want to follow this path.